# How to open a function from dylib?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, dylib

I have added a c++ library .dylib to my objective c cocoa os x app. When I am trying call a function that I wrote into .dylib with my .header class I can't compile because I get the errors. In c+++ project all is correct, but into objective c no.

My viewController:

```
 #import "myHeader.mm"
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    mean(5.8, 5.8);
}
```

My class header:

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

//void donothing(void);
//double mean(double x, double y);
double mean(double x, double y);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The errors are:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mean", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How can solve this? What is the correct form to add .dylib to my project?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add it to Frameworks to make sure it gets linked?

Comment: Yes I added, this appear in Linked Frameworks and Libraires in the Targets